# Spring Batch: How can I specify a class of a step in XML configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In the XML configuration we can possible to add a step. We can do it in a way like this:

```xml
<batch:step id="MyCoolStep"> ... </batch:step>
```

But how can I specify a class of the step?

I want to write something like this

```xml
<batch:step id="MyCoolStep" class="com.test.batch.MyCoolStep"> ... </batch:step>
```

`MyCoolStep` is a `TaskletStep`.

Comment: Read official doc (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html) paragraph 5.2

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your class `MyCoolStep` implements `Tasklet`, you can define a step [like this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#taskletStep):

```xml
<batch:step id="MyCoolStep">
  <batch:tasklet>
    <bean class="com.test.batch.MyCoolStep" />
  </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

without the need to explicitely define a `<bean>` earlier and reference it by id.

But the straight-forward way of doing it is:

```xml
<bean id="myCoolStepBean" class="com.test.batch.MyCoolStep" />

<batch:step id="MyCoolStep">
  <batch:tasklet ref="myCoolStepBean" />
</batch:step>
```

Comment: I got this error: `Configuration problem: The <batch:tasklet/> element may not have more than one of: 'ref' attribute, <chunk/> element, <bean/> attribute, or <ref/> element.  Found: <chunk/> element, <bean/> element.`

Comment: @Finkelson There is a problem with your XML then. In my example, there is only one `<bean>`, no `<chunk>` so this error can't happen.

Comment: `<batch:tasklet ref="myCoolStepBean" />` doesn't work because `myCoolStepBean` isn't a `Tasklet` but a `Step`.

Comment: @Finkelson It is a `Tasklet` if it implements the `Tasklet` interface.

Comment: `MyCoolStep` is a `TaskletStep`.

Comment: @Finkelson Why are you creating a `TaskletStep` and not implementing `Tasklet`?

Answer (score 0):

As Tunaki pointed out, if your step is a `Tasklet`, you can do something like:

```
<batch:step id="MyCoolStep">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <bean class="com.test.batch.MyCoolStep" scope="step" />
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```